# l7-filter does not set markers

Tags: iptables, packet-analyzer

I install l7-filter userspace on ubuntu 12.04 and run it by this command:

```
sudo l7-filter -f /etc/l7.conf -q 1
```

but l7-filter does not set any markers. I set iptables to send forwarding packet to queue 1:

```
sudo iptables -A FORWARD -j NFQUEUE --queue-num 1
```

and load this module:

```
modprob ip_conntrack_netlink and modprob nf_conntrack_ipv4
```

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other iptables rule that matches before the rule shown in your post? You can use `iptables -L FORWARD -n -v` to check your rule hit counters.

Comment: Where is locate of l7 output? how to see it?